# Why is my language flashcard program crashing just because of an if statement?

Tags: c

**I've only done 1 part of the program so choose menu option 1**
Everything was working fine until I added the 
 *if(words[i].errorflag==0){}* in engtotagall(); so that the user has the option of answering his mistakes only after. the program crashes after you pick 1 in the menu. Why is that? I dont see why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int clear(void);
int initialize(void);
int engtotagall(void);
int tagtoengall(void);
int engtotagnoun(void);
int tagtoengnoun(void);
int engtotagverb(void);
int tagtoengverb(void);
int engtotagothers(void);
int tagtoengothers(void);

struct flshcard
{
    char english[10];
    char tagalog[10];
    char speechprt;
    char errorflag;
}words[10];

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        char choice;
        printf("Language Flashcard Practice Program\n");
        printf("1 - English -> Tagalog (All Words)\n2 - Tagalog -> English (All Words)\n3 - English -> Tagalog (Nouns)\n4 - Tagalog -> English (Nouns)\n5 - English -> Tagalog (Verbs)\n6 - Tagalog -> English (Verbs)\n7 - English -> Tagalog (Others)\n8 - Tagalog -> English (Others)\n9 - Exit\n");
        choice=getchar();
        if(choice=='1')
        {
            clear();
            initialize();
            engtotagall();
        }

        else if(choice=='9')
        {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            clear();
            printf("\n%cPlease input a valid option.\n",7);
        }
    }
}

/* Start of function for clearing the pages */
int clear(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Start of the function for initializing the words */
int initialize(void)
{
    /* Making errorflag 0 in all words array */
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        words[i].errorflag=0;
    }
    /* words[0] struct */
    strcpy(words[0].english,"cards");
    strcpy(words[0].tagalog,"baraha");
    words[0].speechprt='n';
    /* words[1] struct */
    strcpy(words[1].english,"punch");
    strcpy(words[1].tagalog,"suntok");
    words[1].speechprt='v';
    /* words[2] struct */
    strcpy(words[2].english,"ugly");
    strcpy(words[2].tagalog,"pangit");
    words[2].speechprt='o';
    /* words[3] struct */
    strcpy(words[3].english,"child");
    strcpy(words[3].tagalog,"bata");
    words[3].speechprt='n';
    /* words[4] struct */
    strcpy(words[4].english,"dance");
    strcpy(words[4].tagalog,"sayaw");
    words[4].speechprt='v';
    /* words[5] struct */
    strcpy(words[5].english,"small");
    strcpy(words[5].tagalog,"maliit");
    words[5].speechprt='o';
    /* words[6] struct */
    strcpy(words[6].english,"cat");
    strcpy(words[6].tagalog,"pusa");
    words[6].speechprt='n';
    /* words[7] struct */
    strcpy(words[7].english,"jump");
    strcpy(words[7].tagalog,"talon");
    words[7].speechprt='v';
    /* words[8] struct */
    strcpy(words[8].english,"dumb");
    strcpy(words[8].english,"bobo");
    words[8].speechprt='o';
    /* words[9] struct */
    strcpy(words[9].english,"frog");
    strcpy(words[9].tagalog,"palaka");
    words[9].speechprt='n';
}
/* Start of function for English to Tagalog (All Words) */
int engtotagall(void)
{
    int i,k,choice;
    char answer[15];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(words[i].errorflag==0) /* I just added this and its now crashing */
        {
            printf("\nWhat is the tagalog for %s?\n",words[i].english);
            gets(answer);
            while(answer[k]!='\0')
            {
                tolower(answer[k]);
            }
            if(strcmp(answer,words[i].tagalog)==0)
            {
                printf("\nYou are correct!!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nWrong answer!!\n");
                words[i].errorflag=1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n1 - Take the whole test again\n2 - Answer your mistakes only\3 - Go back to Menu\n4 - Exit Program\n");
    scanf("%d",choice);
    if(choice==1)
    {
        initialize();
        engtotagall();
    }
    else if (choice==2)
    {
        engtotagall();
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) What do you mean crashing? **Please show the exact error msg**. The same way you don't expect an answer of "there is a bug there", we expect a question with more then "it crashes" (2) This is a *lot* of code - can you **provide minimal compileable example** that still shows the problem at hand? (3) Not related to the question - but, all these `else if` statements are definetly a code smell - A refcator might make your code shorter and more readable.

Comment: gets() is depreciated, ie, only exists for backward compatibility with (very) old code.  Do not use it, use fgets().

Comment: Please minimize your example. In other words, keep only the code in your example that is absolutely necessary to produce your problem. It is very likely that you will then see the problem.

Comment: @amit languageflashcard.exe has stopped working and in the cmd it said Process returned 255 (0xFF) this is in codeblocks btw

Comment: I can see a logical error - if the user selects 'mistakes only', answering correctly does not clear the errorflag.  No help with the crash, though.  In fact, the errorflag should be renamed 'doflag' and initialzed to 1.

Comment: @goldilocks i just replace gets() with fgets()? sorry if im asking a stupid question. because the book im reading never mentioned fgets()

Comment: Methinks that's an old book.  Gets() is depreciated because you cannot prevent an overflow with it.  Fgets() requires two more arguments -- the buffer size, in this case 15 -- and a stream to read from, in this case `stdin`.  See http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#fgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eeek:

```
    while(answer[k]!='\0')
    {
        tolower(answer[k]);
    }
```

k is **uninitialized.**  You are almost certainly out of bounds here from the get go.  That will seg fault and cause your crash.

Plus that loop would be endless if answer[k] != '\0'...

Answer (score 2):

It's the `while` loop where you're trying to convert the string to lower case. You don't initialise `k`, and don't change its value, so the while loop will, in the vast majority of cases, carry on forever. What you probably want here is a `for` loop, something like so:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(answer, 15); i++) {
    answer[i] = tolower(answer[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yup - just spotted that.  Shame that the OP did not simply debug the code.  Single-stepping would have identified the endless loop/exception straightaway.  Can anyone debug anymore?  Is it a lost art?